# How can I reset the game?

Tags: another-case-solved

I want to start over from the very beginning on Another Case Solved. I couldn't find an option for it. Do you have any ideas about how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can go into android settings > downloaded apps > Another Case Solved > Clear Data

Answer (score 0):

What device are you playing this game on? I have it on my Android Note 3 and I just reset the game data by deleting the app and re-downloading from the app store. should be the same for iOS